# Custom DialogFragment onDismiss not called/working

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

The problem is that the onDismiss is not getting fired if I use FragmentsTransaction:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// For a little polish, specify a transition animation
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

// To make it fullscreen, use the 'content' root view as the container
// for the fragment, which is always the root view for the activity
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, _dialogInfo).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

but if I use show(), onDismiss event is called:

```
_dialogInfo.show(getFragmentManager(), DialogFragmentInfo.TAG);
```

The onDismiss is implemented at the custom DialogFragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```

Im not sure why is this and I did not find any explanation in the Documentation.

Answer (score 2):

From the [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), documentation, Lifecycle section:

> This means you should use show(FragmentManager, String) or
>   show(FragmentTransaction, String) to add an instance of DialogFragment
>   to your UI, as these keep track of how DialogFragment should remove
>   itself when the dialog is dismissed.

Presumably, `show()` does some extra work to dismiss the dialog in the expected way.